# Programmatically detect USB over IP connected device

Tags: usb, libusb

Is there a way to detect whether a device is physically connected to a computer, versus an USB over IP connection?

At first glance, libusb offers no way to tell them apart. I am still digging into its code though.

Comment: That libusb does not distinguish them, is a feature of libusb (or USB over ip). To tell them apart, use something low level, like lsusb or /sys/bus/usb

Comment: actually, libusb has VHHUB in its driver names list; if I remove it then it's considered as an unsupported API: I guess that's exactly what I want.

Comment: (that's for VirtualHere only though, so this "solution" is not as complete as I would like it to be...)